# Index variable breaking? Looping in C#, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, indexing

today I have an issue which is driving me up a wall.  I am a novice programmer, currently learning the basics of C#, after learning Java.

Today, I was working on a practice example when I encountered this problem:

[Code Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz7jz.png)

This is a screenshot of my code running, and I have left a print statement inside the loop to show me what my index variable is doing.  As you can see, it is incrementing more than once per each execution of the loop.  I have also gotten the same results when using a while loop, and in other projects.

Here is the code:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many values are you entering");
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the values of the currencies you are converting.");
        decimal[] money = new decimal[value];

        for (int i = 0; i < money.Length; i++)
        {
            money[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.Read());
            Console.WriteLine("i is: "+i);
        }

    }
 }
```

I cannot really proceed with this assignment until I can figure out what is causing this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: In your screenshot, the values are going from 0 to 4 incrementally by 1. What's the problem? Isn't this what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ReadLine()` instead of `Read()` like

```
    Console.WriteLine("How many values are you entering");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(input);

    Console.WriteLine(value +" Please enter the values of the currencies you are converting.");
    decimal[] money = new decimal[value];

    for (int i = 0; i < money.Length; i++)
    {
        money[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("i is: " + i);
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that was it.  Thank you!  But why exactly is that the solution?

Comment: ``ReadLine()`` will let you type until you hit Enter. ``Read()`` returns after you input one character.

Comment: `Read()` Will only return after you hit Enter as well. But in a stream of int value.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Welcome to the wonderful world of C#

Your problem here is `Console.Read()`

`Console.Read()` will give you an int of the character `4` which is your first typed character. And that character will be 52.

So it will loop 52 times.

Instead of `Console.Read()` use `Console.ReadLine()`